# MySQL Use last inserted id from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Through phpmyadmin's interface, I created a stored procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_checkin_create`(IN `userid` INT(10), IN `organizationid` INT(10), IN `checkindate` DATETIME(6), IN `checkoutdate` DATETIME(6), IN `checkinid` INT(10))
NO SQL
Insert Into checkin Values(CheckInID, UserID, OrganizationID, CheckInDate, CheckOutDate) ON DUPLICATE 
KEY UPDATE CheckInID=CheckInID, UserID=userid, OrganizationID=organizationid, checkindate=checkindate, CheckOutDate=checkoutdate$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How do I return `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from this procedure? I know the use-case of:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERTED_ID();
```

But i can't find a way to combine this query in the procedure without getting ambiguous errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Create table statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `checkin`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkin` (
`CheckInID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`OrganizationID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`CheckInDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`CheckOutDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`CheckInID`),
UNIQUE KEY `CheckInID` (`CheckInID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4407 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Show complete CREATE TABLE script for `checkin` table. What constraint may cause ODKU action?

Comment: @Akina check edit

Comment: 1) If PK constraint exists then unique key by the same expression is excess. You'll have two similar indices. Remove ```UNIQUE KEY `CheckInID` (`CheckInID`)``` line. 2) If ODKU is fired due to existing transferred `CheckInID` value then its assigning is excess.

Answer (score 0):

Formally:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `sp_checkin_create` ( IN `userid` INT(10), 
                                IN `organizationid` INT(10), 
                                IN `checkindate` DATETIME(6), 
                                IN `checkoutdate` DATETIME(6), 
                                IN `checkinid` INT(10),
                                OUT inserted_id BIGINT )
NO SQL
BEGIN
    Insert Into checkin 
        Values (CheckInID, UserID, OrganizationID, CheckInDate, CheckOutDate) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        UserID=userid, OrganizationID=organizationid, checkindate=checkindate, CheckOutDate=checkoutdate;
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO inserted_id;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and

```sql
CALL sp_checkin_create(123, 456, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', 789, @last_inserted_id);
SELECT @last_inserted_id;
```

---

Really: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is used only when autoincrement generates new value - so it makes no sense in both cases (both new row inserted with AI explicit assigning and ODKU fired).